# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined (even though it is defined)

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, properties, undefined

So our teacher gave us the "Game Of Life" project. I was really proud of my project until I ran it and got the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined". For those who don't know what Game Of Life is, it's a "game" where you have a matrix (here an 8x8 matrix) and some rules to define if each "person" (the numbers in the matrix) gets to live or not. 1 means alive and 0 means dead. I'll attach the whole project for reference, but here's the part with the error:

```
function process(matrix) { //creates the next generation

var neighbors = 0,
    position = '',
    nextgen = new Array(8); //the matrix has 8 rows
    for (i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
        nextgen[i] = new Array(8);
        for (j = 1; j <= 8; j++) {
            neighbors = neighbors(matrix, i, j);

            //Game Rules
                if (neighbors < 2) {nextgen[i][j] = 0;
                } else if (neighbors == 2) {nextgen[i][j] = 1;
                } else if (neighbors <= 3) {nextgen[i][j] = nextgen[i][j];
                } else {nextgen[i][j] = 0;}
        }
    }
    return nextgen;
}
```

The error appears at `if (neighbors < 2) {nextgen[i][j] = 0;}`. Anyone have any ideas as to why? I defined `nextgen[1][1]` when I defined 8 arrays for `nextgen[1]`, right?

Here's the whole project. the names and everything are in german, so please keep that in mind.

```js
function berechne_nachbarn(matrixb, x, y) { //berechnet die Anzahl der Nachbarn fuer eine Zelle

var zelle = 0,
  nachbarn = 0,
  oben = 0,
  unten = 0,
  links = 0,
  rechts = 0;

//loesung fuer die Randzellen
 if (x == 1) {oben = 1} else {oben = x - 1}
 if (y == 1) {links = 1} else {links = y - 1}
 if (x == 8) {unten = 8} else {unten = x + 1}
 if (y == 8) {rechts = 8} else {rechts = y - 1}
 
for (i = oben; i <= unten; i++) {
 for (j = links; j <= rechts; j++) {
  zelle = parseInt (matrixb[i][j]);
  //loesung fuer leere Zellen
  if (isNaN(zelle)) {zelle = 0;}
  nachbarn = nachbarn + zelle;
 }//ende for j
}//ende for i
//die Zelle selbst ist nicht sein eigener Nachbar!
 nachbarn = nachbarn - matrixb[x][y];
 return nachbarn;
}//ende berechne_nachbarn;

function eingabe() {//erstellt Matrix

var spalte = 0,
  zeile = 0,
  ort = ''
  zelle = 0;
 brett = new Array(8); //8 Zeilen
 for (i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
  brett[i] = new Array(8); //8 Spalten
  for (j = 1; j <= 8; j++) {
   ort = i + 'xx' + j;
    zelle = parseInt(document.formular.elements[ort].value);
    if (isNaN(zelle)) {zelle = 0;}
   brett[i][j] = zelle;
  }//ende for j
 }//ende for i
 return brett;
}//ende eingabe

function verarbeitung(matrix) {//Spielregeln und Verarbeitung

var nachbarn = 0,
  ort = '',
 nextgen = new Array(8); //neue Matrix fuer neue Generation
 for (i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
  nextgen[i] = new Array(8);
  for (j = 1; j <= 8; j++) {
   nachbarn = berechne_nachbarn(matrix, i, j);
   
   //Spielregeln
    if (nachbarn < 2) {nextgen[i][j] = 0;
    } else if (nachbarn == 2) {nextgen[i][j] = 1;
    } else if (nachbarn <= 3) {nextgen[i][j] = nextgen[i][j];
    } else {nextgen[i][j] = 0;}
  }//ende for j
 }//ende for i
 return nextgen;
}//ende verarbeitung

function ausgabe(matrix) {//aendert die Werte im Formular

var ort = '';
 for (i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
  for (j = 1; j <= 8; j++) {
   ort = i + 'xx' + j;
   document.formular.elements[ort].value = matrix[i][j];
  }//ende for j
 }//ende for i
}//ende ausgabe
```

```html
<body>

<h1> Game Of Life</h1>

<form name = "formular">
 <input name = "1xx1" size = "1">
 <input name = "1xx2" size = "1">
 <input name = "1xx3" size = "1">
 <input name = "1xx4" size = "1">
 <input name = "1xx5" size = "1">
 <input name = "1xx6" size = "1">
 <input name = "1xx7" size = "1">
 <input name = "1xx8" size = "1"> <br>
 <input name = "2xx1" size = "1">
 <input name = "2xx2" size = "1">
 <input name = "2xx3" size = "1">
 <input name = "2xx4" size = "1">
 <input name = "2xx5" size = "1">
 <input name = "2xx6" size = "1">
 <input name = "2xx7" size = "1">
 <input name = "2xx8" size = "1"> <br>
 <input name = "3xx1" size = "1">
 <input name = "3xx2" size = "1">
 <input name = "3xx3" size = "1">
 <input name = "3xx4" size = "1">
 <input name = "3xx5" size = "1">
 <input name = "3xx6" size = "1">
 <input name = "3xx7" size = "1">
 <input name = "3xx8" size = "1"> <br>
 <input name = "4xx1" size = "1">
 <input name = "4xx2" size = "1">
 <input name = "4xx3" size = "1">
 <input name = "4xx4" size = "1">
 <input name = "4xx5" size = "1">
 <input name = "4xx6" size = "1">
 <input name = "4xx7" size = "1">
 <input name = "4xx8" size = "1"> <br>
 <input name = "5xx1" size = "1">
 <input name = "5xx2" size = "1">
 <input name = "5xx3" size = "1">
 <input name = "5xx4" size = "1">
 <input name = "5xx5" size = "1">
 <input name = "5xx6" size = "1">
 <input name = "5xx7" size = "1">
 <input name = "5xx8" size = "1"> <br>
 <input name = "6xx1" size = "1">
 <input name = "6xx2" size = "1">
 <input name = "6xx3" size = "1">
 <input name = "6xx4" size = "1">
 <input name = "6xx5" size = "1">
 <input name = "6xx6" size = "1">
 <input name = "6xx7" size = "1">
 <input name = "6xx8" size = "1"> <br>
 <input name = "7xx1" size = "1">
 <input name = "7xx2" size = "1">
 <input name = "7xx3" size = "1">
 <input name = "7xx4" size = "1">
 <input name = "7xx5" size = "1">
 <input name = "7xx6" size = "1">
 <input name = "7xx7" size = "1">
 <input name = "7xx8" size = "1"> <br>
 <input name = "8xx1" size = "1">
 <input name = "8xx2" size = "1">
 <input name = "8xx3" size = "1">
 <input name = "8xx4" size = "1">
 <input name = "8xx5" size = "1">
 <input name = "8xx6" size = "1">
 <input name = "8xx7" size = "1">
 <input name = "8xx8" size = "1"> <br> <br>
 <br>
 <button type = "button" onClick = "{jetzt = eingabe(); nextgen = verarbeitung(jetzt); ausgabe(nextgen);}"> Next Generation </button>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve the issue? Did my answer helped you?

Comment: yes, I did solve the issue. There were two problems. One, in `countNeighbors`, I had `maxY = y -1` instead of `y +1`, which caused the weird property '-1' error. Another problem was in `input`. It gave me an error and said I hadn't defined the matrix. So, before the Game Rules part, I just gave the value 0 to every cell of the board, and then looked at the form and replaced the values with the ones the user had typed in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem guys. It's in the `berechne_nachbarn` function, where the program counts the neighbors of each cell on the game board. More specifically in this part:

```
if (y == 8) {rechts = 8} else {rechts = y - 1}
```

`y - 1` should have been `y + 1`.

Ps. the program works now and I'm so proud of it ^_^